# Meaning of "!!" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

```
elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt list i    = list !! (i-1)
```

This  Function return the i'th element of a list. For Example elementAt "haskell" 5 return 'e'
can anyone explain me whats the meaning of "!!" , i cant find it anywhere .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!!` is a function that returns the `i`th elements of a list (0-indexed).

Its documentation can be found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-):

> List index (subscript) operator, starting from 0. It is an instance of the more general [`genericIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex), which takes an index of any integral type.

Comment: You can use this site to find such definitions: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=!!